# Network profile predicts user's future reputation - outlook is poor

Tags: bug, status-completed, dates, network-profile

I just recently awarded a `+100` bounty to the user [@Mark Bouchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799753/mark-bouchard). After the "day" ended I decided to look at his [reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/421482?tab=reputation) to see the effect. To my amusement, the graph appears to predict his reputation up through October - what's more it seems to think he's in for a big slide tomorrow.

[image: Screenshot of the network profile in question]

Please don't tell him as I'm planning to break the news gently - who knows how he might react after such an emotional rollercoaster.

Comment: Doesn't even match [his past history on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/799753/mark-bouchard?tab=reputation#page_1-view_graph).  Nice catch.

Comment: @MatthewRead - I think it does match actually - your first comment was right. Keep in mind he got another bonus 100 rep from reaching 200 (he was at 187 when I awarded it).

Comment: Ah, looking at it now it seems like it's using the correct data up till today, and then old data for the future.  Which is why it both starts and ends at 235 rep.

Comment: It looks like he takes the news pretty hard, but he'll apparently get over it eventually.

Comment: Could someone add the lottery winning numbers just under the date axis labels?

Comment: Strange, it doesn't happen with my account.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Yeah, I'll get over it. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I seem to have accidentally removed an `ORDER BY Date` from the reputation-graph SQL query in a recent refactoring. It's fixed now. Thanks.